# Textbook confusion regarding "supremum" and "infimum" and "lower bound" and "upper bound"

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

My textbook, *An Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series, Second Edition*, by Phil Dyke, says the following:

> Let $F(x)$ be a function which is defined and is bounded in the interval $a \le x \le b$ and suppose that $m$ and $M$ are respectively the lower and upper bounds of $F(x)$ in this interval (written $[a, b]$ see Appendix C). Take a set of points
>
> $$x_0 = a, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{r - 1}, x_r, \dots, x_n = b$$
>
> and write $\delta_r = x_r - x_{r - 1}$. Let $M_r, m_r$ be the bounds of $F(x)$ in the subinterval $(x_{r - 1}, x_r)$ and form the sums
>
> $$S = \sum_{r = 1}^n M_r \delta_r$$
>
> $$s = \sum_{r = 1}^n m_r \delta_r$$
>
> These are called respectively the upper and lower Riemann sums corresponding to the mode of subdivision. It is certainly clear that $S \ge s$. There are a variety of ways that can be used to partition the interval $(a, b)$ and each way will have (in general) different $M_r$ and $m_r$ leading to different $S$ and $s$. Let $M$ be the minimum of all possible $M_r$ and $m$ be the maximum of all possible $m_r$. A lower bound or supremum for the set $S$ is therefore $M(b - a)$ and an upper bound or infimum for the set $s$ is $m(b - a)$.

Shouldn’t the sentence

> Let $M$ be the minimum of all possible $M_r$ and $m$ be the maximum of all possible $m_r$.

be “$M$ is the maximum of all possible $M_r$ and $m$ is the minimum of all possible $m_r$.”?

And shouldn’t the sentence

> A lower bound or supremum for the set $S$ is therefore $M(b - a)$ and an upper bound or infimum for the set $s$ is $m(b - a)$.

be “An upper bound for the set $S$ is therefore $M(b - a)$ and a lower bound for the set $S$ is $m(b - a)$.”?

Using the definitions of of supremum and infimum from *Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin (see below), the supremum is the least upper bound and the infimum is the greatest lower bound. So not only are supremum and "lower bound" actually different concepts — it seems that they would be contradictory concepts? After all, something cannot be both a supremum and a lower bound. And analogously for infimum and "upper bound”?

[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Wow, that's some sloppy writing ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Apparently this deserved a second edition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a copy of the textbook, so I can't be completely sure what they're trying to state in that section. However, a key thing about using the upper & lower Riemann sums is dealing with their convergence, if any, to a specific value. In that regard, you want to consider how the smallest values of the upper sums approaches the largest values of the lower sums. As such, the sentence

> Let $M$ be the minimum of all possible $M_r$ and $m$ be the maximum of all possible $m_r$.

has an appropriate approach, but as stated in various places, including in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488404/textbook-confusion-regarding-supremum-and-infimum-and-lower-bound-and-upp/3488430?noredirect=1#comment7172938_3488430) to this answer, it's poorly written, but what you're suggesting is not appropriate.

However, you're correct there's a mistake in the next sentence of

> A lower bound or supremum for the set $S$ is therefore $M(b - a)$ and an upper bound or infimum for the set $s$ is $m(b - a)$

The terms "supremum" and "infimum" should be switched around in that sentence.

Comment: I would rather say that “Let $M$ be the minimum of all possible $M_r$” makes no sense. All possible $M_r$, where we’ve fixed a partition or no? If no, then there probably is no minimum; if so, then I guess taking the least of all $m_r$ would make $m(b-a)$ a lower bound for the sum (not set?!) $s$...This passage is frankly just incompetently written.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks for the feedback. You're correct that sentence is not well written. I just meant it had the right idea compared to what the OP was suggesting instead. I've updated my answer  to make this more clear.

Comment: “The minimum of all possible $M_r$ seems to have precious little to do with the minimum of the upper sums. After all, each $M_r$ is the height of just _one_ rectangle. The minimum will not be achievable in general, and if it could, $M(b-a)$ defined in this way would usually be less than the integral. At least that’s how I read it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're right: "Let $M$ be the minimum of all possible $M_r$ and $m$ be the maximum of all possible $m_r$." sounds reasonable when we have "A lower bound or infimum for the set $S$ is therefore $M(b - a)$ and an upper bound or supremum for the set $s$ is $m(b - a)$." The entire section was so poorly written that I confused myself even more trying to fix it.

Comment: @ThePointer You're welcome. I agree that section of text was very poorly worded, so I believe quite a few people would get confused by what they were trying to state, as well as when trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the explanation, as you have transcribed it, is confusing.

Let $T\subset S$ be a bounded subset. Let the set 
$$U = \{ M\in S|\ \forall x \in T: x\leq M \}$$ 
be the set of all the **upper bounds** $M$ of $T$. We then define the **supremum** 
$$\sup T := M'\in U:\forall M\in U,M\geq M' $$

Analogously we take the set of all **lower bounds**
$$L = \{ m\in S|\ \forall x \in T: x\geq m \}$$ 
and define accordingly the **infimum** 
$$\inf T := m'\in L:\forall m\in L,m\leq m' $$

Given this, I'd recommend reading this to understand correctly the construction in your book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Definition